# Codename one login with Linkedin

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, codenameone

I am trying to use Linkedin for login purpose in Codename one, but whenever I am clicking on login button it display blank pop up dialog-box.

[image]

**Below is my code**

```
linked.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

           Oauth2 auth2 = new Oauth2("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization", 
            "XXXXXXXXXX", 
            "https://www.codenameone.com","r_basicprofile", 
            "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken", 
            "XXXXXXXXXX");
   Oauth2.setBackToParent(true);
   auth2.authenticate();
    auth2.createAuthComponent(new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    Log.p(evt.getSource().toString());

            if (evt.getSource() instanceof String) {
                 String token = (String) evt.getSource();
                String expires = Oauth2.getExpires();

                System.out.println("Token=" +token + "Expires in " +expires );
            }
             else {                    
                Exception err = (Exception) evt.getSource();
                err.printStackTrace();
                Dialog.show("Error", "An error occurred while logging in: " + err, "OK", null);
            }
               }
           });

   }
    });
```

Comment: So it doesn't even show you the login form?  (Is this in the simulator?) Check the network monitor in the simulator to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: It doesn't show login in the simulator as well as in the physical device, Can you please tell me if the URL is correct or not or is there any mistake in the code?

Comment: Good point.  Your URL is incorrect.  You shouldn't include any query string in the URL.  Just use `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization`.  The query string will be added automatically by the `Oauth2` class.

Comment: By the way, when you are posting code on a public platform, always leave out sensitive data like your API keys/tokens or replace them with `xxx xxx xxx`.

Comment: That credential belongs to the deleted linked in application

Answer (score 1):

Here I got the solution of the above problem.

**Working code:**

```
linked.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {


               Oauth2 auth2 = new Oauth2("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization", 
                "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
                "https://www.codenameone.com","r_basicprofile", 
                "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", 
                "XXXXXXXXXXXXX");

       //auth2.authenticate();
        auth2.showAuthentication(new ActionListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                       AccessToken token = (AccessToken) evt.getSource();
                       JSONObject object = new JSONObject(token);
                       try {
                           TOKEN = object.getString("token");
                           Log.p(TOKEN);
                       } catch (JSONException ex) {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               });
                Oauth2.setBackToParent(true);


       }
        });
```

**Above code successfully authenticate linked in user and in response we get token after successful login in TOKEN variable.**